# Killing all workers/threads ThreadPoolExecutor

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.6

I have been trying for the past day to come up with a fix to my current problem.

I have a python script which is supposed to count up using threads and perform requests based on each thread.

Each thread is going through a function called doit(), which has a while True function. This loop only breaks if it meets a certain criteria and when it breaks, the following thread breaks as well.

What I want to achieve is that once one of these threads/workers gets status code 200 from their request, all workers/threads should stop. My problem is that it won't stop even though the criteria is met.

Here is my code:

```
import threading
import requests
import sys
import urllib.parse
import concurrent.futures
import simplejson
from requests.auth import HTTPDigestAuth
from requests.packages import urllib3
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

def doit(PINStart):
    PIN = PINStart
    while True:
        req1 = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(data), headers=headers1, verify=False)
        if str(req1.status_code) == "200":
            print(str(PINs))
            c0 = req1.content
            j0 = simplejson.loads(c0)
            AuthUID = j0['UserId']
            print(UnAuthUID)
            AuthReqUser()
            #Kill all threads/workers if any of the threads get here.
            break
        elif(PIN > (PINStart + 99)):
              break
        else:
            PIN+=1

def main():
    threads = 100
    threads = int(threads)
    Calcu = 10000/threads
    NList = [0]
    for i in range(1,threads):
        ListAdd = i*Calcu
        if ListAdd == 10000:
            NList.append(int(ListAdd))
        else:
            NList.append(int(ListAdd)+1)

    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=threads) as executor:
        tGen = {executor.submit(doit, PinS): PinS for PinS in NList}
        for NLister in concurrent.futures.as_completed(tGen):
            PinS = tGen[NLister]



if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I understand why this is happening. As I only break the while True loop in one of the threads, so the other 99 (I run the code with 100 threads by default) doesn't break until they finish their count (which is running through the loop 100 times or getting status code 200).

What I originally did was to define a global variable at the top of the code and I changed while Counter < 10000, meaning it will run the loop for all workers until Counter is greater than 10000. And inside the loop it will increment the global variable. This way, when a worker gets status code 200, I set Counter (my global variable) to for example 15000 (something above 10000), so all the other workers stop running the loop 100 times.

This did not work. When I add that into the code, all threads instantly stop, doesn't even run through the loop once.

Here is an example code of this solution:

```
import threading
import requests
import sys
import urllib.parse
import concurrent.futures
import simplejson
from requests.auth import HTTPDigestAuth
from requests.packages import urllib3
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
global Counter
def doit(PINStart):
    PIN = PINStart
    while Counter < 10000:
        req1 = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(data), headers=headers1, verify=False)
        if str(req1.status_code) == "200":
            print(str(PINs))
            c0 = req1.content
            j0 = simplejson.loads(c0)
            AuthUID = j0['UserId']
            print(UnAuthUID)
            AuthReqUser()
            #Kill all threads/workers if any of the threads get here.
            Counter = 15000
            break
        elif(PIN > (PINStart + 99)):
            Counter = Counter+1
            break
        else:
            Counter = Counter+1
            PIN+=1

def main():
    threads = 100
    threads = int(threads)
    Calcu = 10000/threads
    NList = [0]
    for i in range(1,threads):
        ListAdd = i*Calcu
        if ListAdd == 10000:
            NList.append(int(ListAdd))
        else:
            NList.append(int(ListAdd)+1)

    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=threads) as executor:
        tGen = {executor.submit(doit, PinS): PinS for PinS in NList}
        for NLister in concurrent.futures.as_completed(tGen):
            PinS = tGen[NLister]



if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Any idea on how I can kill all workers once I get status code 200 from one of the requests I sending out?

Comment: By sort-of: (1) You're not synchronizing access to `Counter`. That means threads can miss updates and go through the loop at least one extra time, and it means you can end up under-counting (if that 10000 limit is there for a reason). And (2) you're not checking `Counter` until after you've downloaded and processed a whole file, which could take seconds.

Comment: @abarnert, all the threads should stop if counter hits 10000 or if one of the 10000 requests gets status code 200. What is a done flag?

Comment: @NathanHughes Calling `shutdown` will just tell the executor to stop giving out new tasks. Since he's manually batched things up so he only has a small number of tasks each of which does a huge number of loops, that won't help. (Of course a better design that let the executor do what it does best would mean `shutdown` is more useful, but…)

Comment: A "done flag" is just a `done = False` that you set to `done = True` when done. But if you actually need to stop at 10000, then never mind that part.

Comment: @adbarnert, awesome. It totally worked by putting a global variable inside the function and using the counter that way. Will mark your first comment as the solution. Thanks mate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're *not* using a global variable.

To use a global variable in a function, you have to put the `global` statement *in that function*, not at the top level. Because you didn't, the `Counter` inside `doit` is a local variable. Any variable that you assign to anywhere in a function is local, unless you have a `global` (or `nonlocal`) declaration.

And the first time you use that local `Counter` is right at the top of the `while` loop, before you've assigned anything to it. So, it's going to raise an `UnboundLocalError` immediately.

This exception will be propagated back to the main thread as the result of the future. Which you would have seen, except that you never actually evaluate your futures. You just do this:

```
   tGen = {executor.submit(doit, PinS): PinS for PinS in NList}
   for NLister in concurrent.futures.as_completed(tGen):
        PinS = tGen[NLister]
```

So, you get the `PinS` corresponding to the function you ran, but you don't look at the result or exception; you just ignore it. Hence you don't see that you're getting back 100 exceptions, any of which would have told you what was actually wrong. This is equivalent to having a bare `except: pass` in non-threaded code. Even if you don't want to check the result of your futures in "production" for some reason, you definitely should do it when debugging a problem.

Anyway, just put the `global` in the right place, and your bug is fixed.

---

However, you do have at least two other problems.

First, sharing globals between threads without synchronizing them is not safe. In CPython, thanks to the GIL, you never get a segfault because of it, and you often get away with it completely, but you often don't. You can miss counts because two threads tried to do `Counter = Counter + 1` at the same time, so they both incremented it from 42 to 43. And you can get a stale value in the `while Counter < 10000:` check and go through the loop an extra time.

Second, you don't check the `Counter` until you've finished downloading and processing a complete requests. This could take seconds, maybe even minutes depending on your timeout settings. And add that to the fact that you might go through the loop an extra time before knowing it's time to quit…

Comment: Now that the code works the way it should, I have a small problem. When one of the 10000 requests gets status code 200, it should run another function called AuthReqUser(), but this function doesn't run even if I have it inside the doit function. I can't put it under main() function which runs at startup since it will run the AuthReqUser() instantly alongside the threads. Anyway for this AuthReqUser() to be ran once we get status code 200 and status code 200 only?

Comment: I was thinking of putting a while true loop and checking if counter is 15000 and if it is, it will run AuthReqUser().

Comment: @JamesRicky Why can't you run it in the main thread, just after the `with … executor:` block? You won't get there until all the background threads are done.